# Entity Framework Core not resetting Sql Connection pool?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

> InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed
>   prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred
>   because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was
>   reached.

For some reason i usually get this error message once in awhile when testing locally

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=myDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

Just when i pressed log in and where it does the check in database, it just takes forever until it gives me the exception with the error i just posted. Why does this happen? I think this hasn't happened on the production server yet or i just missed it, but would be nice to know why this happens.

Comment: Then probably the lifetime or scope of your database connection classes is incorrect, keeping connections open. Create a [mre] of your code that reproduces the issue, and[edit] your question to show it.